# Array VBA not getting populated with the first value assigned

Tags: vba, outlook

Trying to build a macro to copy my To-Do List to Task list folder in Outlook. I want to have some sort of validation against the Task list, to not duplicate the Tasks when I run the macro. So my 
plan is to compare the subject arrays of To-Do and Tasks.

```
Set TaskFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
i = 0 
For Each CurrentItem In TaskFolder.Items
   If TypeOf CurrentItem Is Outlook.TaskItem Then
        Dim otMail As Outlook.TaskItem: Set otMail = CurrentItem
        arrTaskSubject(i) = otMail.Subject
   End If
   i = i + 1
   ReDim Preserve arrTaskSubject(i)
Next CurrentItem
```

I have only 2 task in my Tasks outlook foolder with the subject TASK1 and TASK2. However when I try to save the elements to an array from task list, it gets saved only the last element in the array.

Breakpointing the Next CurrentItem I get these values:

[image]

At the next excution cycle I have these values:
[image]

Why is not saving both TASK1 and TASK2 to arrTaskSubject array?

Comment: How you have declared the variable arrTaskSubject ?

Comment: Dim arrTaskSubject() As String. That was the issue, I had to redim the array before assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the beginning the array doesn't have a size, so that's why the Task1 is not assigned to it

when it moves to Task2 it assigns it to i=1, and then redims to size 2

you can change the code in the following way:

```
Set TaskFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
i = 0 
For Each CurrentItem In TaskFolder.Items
   If TypeOf CurrentItem Is Outlook.TaskItem Then
        ReDim Preserve arrTaskSubject(i)
        Dim otMail As Outlook.TaskItem: Set otMail = CurrentItem
        arrTaskSubject(i) = otMail.Subject
        i = i + 1
   End If
Next CurrentItem
```

this will populate the array with Task1 at index 0 and Task 2 at index 1

if you want to keep empty items in the array if there are any then you should move the i increment out of the if